# Javascript Regex Match between pound signs

Tags: javascript, regex

Quick. I have a string: `#user 9#I'm alive!` and I want to be about to pull out "user 9".

So far Im doing:

```
    if(variable.match(/\#/g)){
            console.log(variable):
    }
```

But the output is still the full line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.split()`, in order to pull out your desired item.

```
var variable = variable.split("#");
console.log(variable[1]);
```

`.split()` turns your string into an array, with the first variable as a separator.

Of course, if you just want regex alone, you could do:

```
console.log(variable.match(/([^#]+)/g));
```

This will again give you an array of the items, but a smaller one as it doesn't use the empty value before the hash as an item.  Further, as stated by @Stephen P, you will need to use a capture group(`()`) to capture the items you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more along these lines...

```
var thetext="#user 9#I'm alive!";
thetext.match(/\#([^#]+)\#/g);
```

You want to introduce a *capturing group* (the part in the parentheses) to collect the text in between the pound signs.

You may want to use `.exec()` instead of `.match()` depending on what you're doing.
Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503) to the SO question *"How do you access the matched groups in a javascript regex?"*